# How to populate HighCharts with temperature sensor values

Tags: php, highcharts

I have a datababes with a table called "log" where I stored sensor values picked each minute.

The rows are: SensorId (I have 3 sensors ), Date (auto created by MySQL) and Value.

Now I want to plot this values with HighCharts, concretely HighStock.

How I translate the database values to a json highstock-underestable array?

Thanks!

Comment: I advice to read Highcharts dosc, see [here](http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing)